# iOS Game Center submit float instead of int64_t

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit, gkscore

I am trying to submit a `float` of two decimal length to my Game Center leaderboard, however the only format allowed to submit with is `int64_t`. I am using the default Apple report score method:

```
- (void)reportScore:(int64_t)score forCategory:(NSString *)category {
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category];   
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) {
        [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(scoreReported:) withArg: NULL error: error];
    }];
}
```

I am trying to use this method to provide the score to the report score method:

```
- (IBAction)increaseScore {
    self.currentScore = self.currentScore + 1;
    currentScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lld", self.currentScore];
    NSLog(@"%lld", self.currentScore);
}
```

Please help, I have been googling like crazy and cannot find the answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only submit 64 bit integers as scores to a leaderboard. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html):

> To Game Center, a score is just a
>   64-bit integer value reported by your
>   application. You are free to decide
>   what a score means, and how your
>   application calculates it. When you
>   are ready to add the leaderboard to
>   your application, you configure
>   leaderboards on iTunes Connect to tell
>   Game Center how a score should be
>   formatted and displayed to the player.
>   Further, you provide localized strings
>   so that the scores can be displayed
>   correctly in different languages. A
>   key advantage of configuring
>   leaderboards in iTunes Connect is that
>   the Game Center application can show
>   your game’s scores without you having
>   to write any code.

That doc page should tell you about formatting your score. It sounds like in order to display float-like scores you will have to tinker with the format settings in iTunes Connect.

**Update**

Try this for increaseScore:

```
- (IBAction) increaseScore {      
     self.currentScore = self.currentScore + 5; 
     float score = (float)self.currentScore / 100.0f;
     currentScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", score]; 
     NSLog(@"%lld", self.currentScore);
}
```

Comment: scoreReporter.value = (int64_t)(score * 100.0f); this formats the code properly. Now my problem is the increase score method which needs to be made into a float

Comment: I am not quite clear what's going on in your increaseScore method. How does that connect to the previous code? I don't know what the datatypes of the variables involved are.

Comment: I found this resource but cannot implement it properly: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/10768

Comment: - (IBAction) increaseScore
{
    
    self.currentScore = (float)(self.currentScore / 100.0f);
    self.currentScore = self.currentScore + 0.5;
    
 currentScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.02f", self.currentScore];
    NSLog(@"%lld", self.currentScore);

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `self.currentScore = (float)(self.currentScore / 100.0f);` What is the definition of `currentScore`? Is it int64_t or float?

Answer (score 6):

GameCenter only accepts int64_t

The only difference between values that **appear** like floats or decimal values and those that appear as integers is the position of the decimal mark, while in fact all of them are int64_t.

If your internal representation is a double and you configured game center to show 3 digits after the decimal mark you have to convert it to an integer by multiplying with 10^3 and casting to integer.

```
int64_t gameCenterScore = (int64_t)(doubleValue * 1000.0f)
```

Comment: don't forget those second parentheses for order of operation, or doubleValue will be cast first, before being multiplied by the chosen factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the GKScore.h file.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign)            int64_t     value;              // The score value as a 64bit integer.
```

So float value now is not available.

Comment: yes, but gamekit allows you to post float scores to leaderboards, there must be a way

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem.